# Configure Nginx for Socket.io - 502 Bad gateway

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

I am trying to configure my app compose of Node + Express + Socket.io into production on my server but after many hours I'm still getting the same errors.

Index.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);


var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);
```

Index.twig

```
    <script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>  
        const socket = io();
...
```

conf Nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
    location /socket.io/ {
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/; 
    }

}
```

Erros 502 I get :

```
socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 502 (Bad Gateway)
```